# What is the expectation of absolute difference

Tags: mean, expected-value, descriptive-statistics, differences

Given:
E(|X-R|) =2.5

E(|L-X|)= 3

where X, R, L are assumed to be normally distributed and independent. Standard deviations of |X-R| and |L-X| are known.

what is E(|L-R|) ?

Comment: (1) Are all three distributions assumed to be the same? (2) Note that even when the standard deviations are known, there will be at least two distinct answers.

Comment: And what are the two answers? The standard deviations are known.

Comment: Consider the case where the SDs are all tiny and the mean of $X$ is $0.$ That implies the mean of $R$ must be near $\pm 2.5$ and the mean of $L$ must be near $\pm 3.$ Those four possibilities yield two answers near $0.5$ and $5.5.$

Comment: Ok... so the answers are distinct and it's not possible to say in one number what is E(|L-R|) ? Can it be an average of the two, so 3 ?

Comment: No--it must be one or the other.  Averaging two correct answers doesn't produce another correct answer!

Comment: This is in fact a question based on a practical problem and it has to be that there is only one really correct answer. Does it imply it is not possible to find out this answer? Also, in fact it is not possible to assume the mean of X is zero.

Comment: The mean-zero assumption is irrelevant; I adopted it only to provide a concrete example.  I hope it's obvious that your information is invariant when all variables are shifted by the same amount.  If there's only one truly correct answer, then you need to select it based on additional information.

Comment: I don't have additional information at the moment - this is interesting that it's not possible to get one answer given this information.

Comment: It could be that I was wrong to assume that X, R, L are independent - would that change something? I should rather say |X-R| and |L-X| and |L-R| are independent. Does it have any implications for the answer?

Comment: Independence (or lack thereof) does not affect expectations.  The issue comes down to the basic number fact that the *numbers* $|x-r|$ and $|x-l|$ do not uniquely determine $|l-r|.$

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and talking about this , it’s much more clear to me now. It’s good to have a second opinion. I would mark your second comment as an answer if I could.